# Javascript "..." arguments

Tags: javascript, bind, monads, variadic-functions

While watching http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b0EF0VTs9Dc, I found this kind of javascript code

```
function unit(value) {
    var monad = Object.create(prototype);
    monad.bind = function (func, args) {
        return func.apply(undefined,
                       [value].concat(
                           Array.prototype.slice.apply(args || [])));
    }
    return monad;
}
```

is rewritten as

```
function unit(value) {
    var monad = Object.create(prototype);
    monad.bind = function (func, args) {
        return func(value, ...args);
    }
    return monad;
}
```

However the latter one doesn't running in Chrome and firefox ( I didn't try IE ). Is it something new in Javascript and not supported in current browsers yet?

Comment: [Rest Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/rest_parameters) - works in Firefox Aurora/Nightly. You can also [listen](https://gpodder.net/podcast/a-minute-with-brendan/the-arguments-argument-2) or [watch](http://vimeo.com/27911873) Brendan Eich talk about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it something new in Javascript and not supported in current browsers yet?

Yes, that's part of the next version of the language specification (ECMAScript 6), which is still a draft.

It's only supported by Firefox, and only experimentally, as stated in the [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/rest_parameters) posted by Dan Heberden.

Part of that can be achieved in current JavaScript. For example, to get all extra, unnamed arguments passed to a function:

```
function f(x) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, f.length);
    console.log(args);
}
f(1,2,3); // logs [2, 3]
```

Or, to pass them along to another function:

```
function f(someFunc) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, f.length);
    someFunc.apply(null, args);
}
f(function(a,b){
    console.log(a, b);
}, 1, 2); // logs 1 2
```